# Trying to modify "Read more" link in parent theme

Tags: php, wordpress, function, filter, themes

My parent them has a custom "Read more" function. I want to change the text and add to my child theme function.php.

Here is parent them function

```
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'newslite_excerpt_length', 999 );
```

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'newslite_implement_read_more' ) ) :

    function newslite_implement_read_more( $more ) {

        $flag_apply_excerpt_read_more = apply_filters( 'newslite_filter_excerpt_read_more', true );
        if ( true !== $flag_apply_excerpt_read_more ) {
            return $more;
        }

        $output = $more;
        $read_more_text = __('continue reading','newslite');
        if ( ! empty( $read_more_text ) ) {
            $output = ' <div class="read-more-text"><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" class="read-more">' . esc_html( $read_more_text ) . '</a></div>';
            $output = apply_filters( 'newslite_filter_read_more_link' , $output );
        }
        return $output;

    }

endif;
```

```
add_action( 'excerpt_more', 'newslite_implement_read_more' );
```

Comment: How do you want to modify it. Please update your question. Have you attempted any changes?

Comment: want to change the "read more" text. I am building a child theme so don't want to just modify the parent theme.

Comment: I would like this function to load from my child theme, so how do I get my template to read mine first so I can have a different "read more" text?

Comment: added filter before and action after

Comment: maybe it would be easier to just remove filter and add a new one?

Answer (score 0):

I would just remove their function, and create your own custom one.

```
add_action( 'excerpt_more', 'custom_newslite_implement_read_more', 9999 );
function custom_newslite_implement_read_more( $more ) {

    remove_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'newslite_excerpt_length', 999 );

    $flag_apply_excerpt_read_more = apply_filters( 'custom_newslite_filter_excerpt_read_more', true );
    if ( true !== $flag_apply_excerpt_read_more ) {
        return $more;
    }

    $output = $more;
    $read_more_text = __('read more','newslite'); // change read more to whatever you want
    if ( ! empty( $read_more_text ) ) {
        $output = ' <div class="read-more-text"><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" class="read-more">' . esc_html( $read_more_text ) . '</a></div>';
        $output = apply_filters( 'custom_newslite_filter_read_more_link' , $output );
    }
    return $output;

}
```

Comment: What I would like to do is, without altering parent files at all, either: A) add code to my function.php file that removes this function and then create my own  - or B) copy the parent code and simply change the text string for the button. I have tried B but since the parent function loads first, it isn't recognizing my copy of it. Hope that make sense and thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Try code:

```
   function new_excerpt_more($more) {
       global $post;
       return '… <a href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '">' . 'Read More &raquo;' . '</a>';
   }
   add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');
```

Answer (score 0):

I copied the parent function (everything inside the if statement) to my child functions.php file. then simply changed the text string. This worked.

```
function newslite_implement_read_more( $more ) {

    $flag_apply_excerpt_read_more = apply_filters( 'newslite_filter_excerpt_read_more', true );
    if ( true !== $flag_apply_excerpt_read_more ) {
        return $more;
    }

    $output = $more;
    $read_more_text = __('More','newslite');
    if ( ! empty( $read_more_text ) ) {
        $output = ' <div class="read-more-text"><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" class="read-more">' . esc_html( $read_more_text ) . '</a></div>';
        $output = apply_filters( 'newslite_filter_read_more_link' , $output );
    }
    return $output;

}
```